How to configure FunctionsWebApplication and WebHost in the same HostBuilder
I am trying to run a gRPC service in an app that is already configured to run an Azure Function App.
To add gRPC functionality to the same HostBuilder, I call the ConfigureWebHost method of the HostBuilder. However, once I call ConfigureWebHostBuilder, the gRPC server works, but the AzureFunction calls don't get executed. I get the following error on the console.
Failed to proxy request to the worker. Retrying in 50ms. Attempt 1 of 3.
Following is the sample code that I've used to try and configure Azure Function Apps and gRPC via the same host builder.
IHost host = new HostBuilder()
 .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication(builder =>
 {
     builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
     {
         options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
     });
 })
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((
    hostContext,
    configuration) =>
{
    configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, false)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, false)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, false)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
})
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddGrpcClient<Greeter.GreeterClient>(options =>
    {
        // Configure the gRPC client options here
        options.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:7293");
    });
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();


    IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;

    services
        .AddBindings()
        .AddConfig(configuration)
        .AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
})
.ConfigureWebHost(webBuilder =>
{
     webBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
     {
         services.AddGrpc();
     });

     webBuilder.Configure(app =>
     {
         app.UseRouting();

         app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
         {
             endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();

         });
     });

    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
        // Setup a HTTP/2 endpoint without TLS.
        options.ListenLocalhost(7105, o => o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);
    });
})
.Build();

host.Run();

I am new to the .NET eco system, hence any guidance on how this can be achieved, or whether it can be achieved at all would be very helpful.

Please share the function code and .csproj file?

I have achieved it in the following way-

I have created a GrpcGreeter service project which has all the default code in it. I have referred this Doc.
Then, created another project for Azure timer isolated function in the same solution which has below given code.

function1.cs-
using GrpcGreeter;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp67
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly Greeter.GreeterClient _client;

        public Function1(Greeter.GreeterClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("* * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, FunctionContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger("Function1");
            logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            var reply = await _client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "Azure Function" });
            logger.LogInformation("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
        }
    }
}

program.cs-
using GrpcGreeter;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        // Add gRPC client service
        services.AddGrpcClient<Greeter.GreeterClient>(options =>
        {
            //make sure to add the correct url below
            options.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:7096");
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.27.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.63.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.64.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.3-preview2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\GrpcGreeter\GrpcGreeter\GrpcGreeter.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="..\..\GrpcGreeter\GrpcGreeter\Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Both" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Start the GrpcGreeter service and then start the function project to get the expected response from function.
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5801 Commit hash: N/A +5ac2f0975e5ea9ef68ff (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669

[2024-06-07T09:01:42.984Z] Found C:\Users\*****\source\repos\FunctionApp67\FunctionApp67\FunctionApp67.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-06-07T09:01:47.125Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 18804) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-06-07T09:01:47.179Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: timerTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-06-07T09:01:48.067Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-06-07T14:31:48.0301543+05:30', Id=c1a3476e-bc68-4619-8b8e-ff1c5c3fa157)
[2024-06-07T09:01:48.221Z] C# Timer trigger function executed at: 6/7/2024 2:31:48 PM
[2024-06-07T09:01:48.234Z] Start processing HTTP request POST https://localhost:7096/greet.Greeter/SayHello
[2024-06-07T09:01:48.235Z] Sending HTTP request POST https://localhost:7096/greet.Greeter/SayHello
[2024-06-07T09:01:48.347Z] Received HTTP response headers after 106.2934ms - 200
[2024-06-07T09:01:48.348Z] End processing HTTP request after 117.1232ms - 200
[2024-06-07T09:01:48.356Z] Greeting: Hello Azure Function
[2024-06-07T09:01:48.405Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=c1a3476e-bc68-4619-8b8e-ff1c5c3fa157, Duration=364ms)

